# Aligning List Elements Vertically at the Bottom

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

## Question

I am trying to put every `li` at the bottom of the `ul`, making the bottom of every element (not the text, the actual block element of the ui, whether that's the image or the whole `li` of text) touching. This should be a simple problem with `vertical-align:bottom` and `display:table-cell` being the fix, but for some reason I haven't been able to get it to work. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Its likely there's a question that already answered this, but I've spent a lot of time searching. If there's one that applies, please just point me to it.

### Example

[image]

### Fiddle With It:

http://jsfiddle.net/rxg9m/

### HTML

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="left">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="left">Product</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="Javid Logo"/></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="right">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="right">Info</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    font-family:Calibri;
}
#outer {
    text-align:center;
}
#inner {
    display:inline-block;
}
nav ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    bottom:0;
    list-style:none;
}
nav li {
    float:left;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
nav li a {
    padding:16px 8px 16px 8px;
    margin:0px;
    width:120px;
    display:block;
    background-color:lightblue;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-emphasis:none;
    color:black;
    border:0px none black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
nav li a.left {
    text-align:left;
}
nav li a.right {
    text-align:right;
}
#logo {
    padding:0px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    line-height:0px;
    border:0px none black;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simply remove the `float:left` from `nav li`. Everything else is in order.

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mXTG6/

Answer (score 3):

#### Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/rxg9m/2/

```
nav li a {
    padding:32px 8px 0px 8px;
```

You are setting a `padding` on the bottom. You should counteract that and `double your padding` on top and set your `padding-bottom` to `0`.

Because you had `padding` applied, it **WAS** on the bottom technically. The only problem is it also expanded all the way to the top.

---

#### Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/rxg9m/4/

Aligning WITHIN the `ul` is very tricky, and your best bet would be to just align the `ul` inside of a `wrapper` of sorts. That way, you can use `position:relative;` on the `wrapper` and `absolutely position` your `ul` to the bottom. And yeah, style from there.

## Basic Example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
</div>

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.wrapper {
    height:200px;
    background:#CCC;
    position:relative;
}
ul {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;    
    width:100%;
}
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left; 
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:25%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: And you don't need to downvote an answer out of spite that the question wasn't formatted correctly. :-)

Comment: This isnt the fix i was looking for, see the updated question.

Comment: No problem, writing up a use-case.

Comment: Thank you. I hope my question was specific enough now

Comment: Well, I'm going to have to align the whole `UL` to the bottom.

Comment: anything that does what i want (with simple explanation) would be acceptable. thank you for the interest.

Comment: Referring to my code, would the `nav` be acceptable as a wrapper?

Comment: No reason why not. One thing you'll have to change is your `img` and position it OUTSIDE of the `ul` (otherwise the `li` elements will see `bottom` as a different value). But yes, just ensure your `nav` has a `position:relative;` and it should work with a little bit of modification.

Comment: Well, the way you're coding it is pretty hard to read and traverse with CSS. Like I said, you will need a few modifications. You still have paddings and floats and all other sorts of things that will break it.

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: Here is a quick example to show you it works (tweaked some values) [here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/rxg9m/6/). I know it's not perfect, but it's not our job to code your project, just provide a solution. Deleted `padding`, deleted `float`, added `background` to `outerdiv`, set `innerdiv` as position `relative` instead of `nav`. Few things.

Comment: Just play around with it. If you had a more specific question, more than happy to help. If you believe this has helped you solve the problem, please select the green checkbox next to the voting arrows.

Comment: I do have a specific question. It was the one asked. I could have just as easily rewritten my code to align it at the bottom, but i had specific requirements (block display links, proper centering of the ul, and an image) that you just worked around or removed. im not asking you to write my code for me, just properly address the question.

Comment: I figured it out, it was simply the `float:left` from `nav li`. Thank you for your help, you pointed me in the right direction, for that a +1.

Comment: No, your answer did not answer my question. I solved it myself. The upvote is for your help.

Comment: Quite happy to assist for almost an hour and provide 2 working solutions for future coders to reference from. But they won't. Have a good one @JimHurley

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rxg9m/1/

Your issue was with this

```
nav li a {
    padding:16px 8px 16px 8px;
```

change it to

```
nav li a {
    padding:16px 8px 0px 8px;
```

also, if you want the height to be the same, you can just do 32px instead of 16px for the first padding value, like Nicholas did in his answer.

Comment: Haha, great minds think alike. I clicked the button to submit and yours popped up with the EXACT same lines of code haha (other than the padding thing).

Comment: Ill have to be more specific; I want the elements themselves touching at the bottom, regardless of height.

Comment: Jim, I've expanded on that a bit in my answer.

Comment: Ive expanded a bit on my question as well. This doesn't address my problem, im sorry i wasnt specific enough the first time.